# How to generate a pdf in landscape mode from a html output using itext 5.1.1

Tags: html, pdf, xslt, itext, landscape

We are planning to generate a pdf in landscape mode by passing html text as a input. Further, **the pdf is getting generated in landscape mode however the content is in portrait mode**. 
Following are the steps that we are using to execute the above requirement.

1) Receive the xml content from the source system.

2) Use an xsl to generate html output from the xml.

3) Pass html output as input to pdf java class, further the class will generate the pdf in landscape mode.

sample xml file:http://www.filedropper.com/resettsample

sample xsl file:http://www.filedropper.com/resettcopy

java code

> ```
>           package testproject;
>
>
>           import java.io.File;
>           import java.io.FileOutputStream;
>           import java.io.StringReader;
>           import java.io.StringWriter;
>
>           import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
>
>           import java.util.Date;
>
>           import javax.xml.transform.Result;
>           import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
>           import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
>           import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
>           import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
>
>           import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
>           import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
>           import com.itextpdf.text.RectangleReadOnly;
>           import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
>           import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper;
>
>           public class PDFTest {
>           public static void main(String[] args) {
>           try {
>
>           new PDFTest().PDFCreateRequest();
>
>           } catch (Exception ex) {
>           ex.printStackTrace();
>           }
>           }
>
>
>           public static void PDFCreateRequest() throws Exception {
>
>           StringWriter stringWriter = null;
>           Result result = null;
>           TransformerFactory tFactory = null;
>           Transformer transformer = null;
>           String strXMLFile = null;
>           String strXSLFile = null;
>           String strHTMLString = null;
>           String strFeedFolderPath = null;
>           String strPDFFileName = null;
>           String strPDFFileNameWithExtension = null;
>           String strPDFFile = null;
>           Document document = null;
>           PdfWriter pdfWriter = null;
>
>           strXMLFile = "C:\\RESETT_sample.xml";
>           String timeStamp =
>           new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());
>
>
>           strXSLFile = "C:\\RESETT_Copy.xsl";
>           stringWriter = new StringWriter();
>           result = new StreamResult(stringWriter);
>           tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
>
>           transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(strXSLFile));
>
>           transformer.transform(new StreamSource(strXMLFile), result);
>
>           strHTMLString = stringWriter.toString();
>           System.out.println("###### [HTML output " + strHTMLString);
>
>           strPDFFileName = "RESETT_" + timeStamp;
>           strFeedFolderPath = "C:\\pdfdocuments";
>
>           strPDFFileNameWithExtension = strPDFFileName + ".pdf";
>           strPDFFile =
>           strFeedFolderPath + File.separator + strPDFFileNameWithExtension;
>
>           // This is for PDF Landscape output
>           document =
>           new Document(new RectangleReadOnly(842, 595), 10, 10, 75, 20);
>
>
>           // This is for PDF Portrait output
>           document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 75, 20);
>
>           pdfWriter =
>           PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(strPDFFile));
>           document.open();
>           XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(pdfWriter, document,
>           new StringReader(strHTMLString));
>           document.close();
>           }   
>           }
> ```

Any suggestions on how to achieve the required output is appreciated.

Thanks
Sandeep

Comment: include what you tried till now?

Comment: Hi Piyush, I have updated the post with additional information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to the [XML Worker examples](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker) and take whatever example you want, but change the following line:

```
Document document = new Document();
```

Into something like this:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
```

This will result in the document being in landscape instead of in portrait.

You may need to upgrade your version of iText/XML Worker (make sure you always use versions of iText and XML Worker that correspond).

Comment: Thanks Bruno. I selected ParseHTMLTable1,java example and implemented what you mentioned above. 

What i observed is the pdf document gets changed from portrait to landscape. However the HTML table content remains at the same location. I would want the content( expand/shrink) to adjust alongwith the document orientation.

Please let me know how to achieve that or if my understanding is wrong somewhere.

Thanks.
Sandeep

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. PDF is not HTML: everything has a fixed position on the page. If your table has the same dimensions regardless of the orientation of the page, your table may contain information about the widths of the table and columns. Moreover, you never answered @Piyush's question: what did you try? Show use a simple HTML file that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I got your point about the width of the table and columns. I am working on that. Meanwhile, I have updated the post with a sample scenario. 
Thanks.

Comment: I was able to achieve the desired pdf landscape result using the same above code by only updating the XMLWorker and Itextpdf jar versions. Thanks

Comment: @SandeepSingh Great! I'll update my answer and maybe you can accept it, so that people can see that the problem is solved now.